# Print character vector as LaTeX list in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Is there an option or a function which takes a vector like this

```
c("toto", "tata" ,"tutu", "toto", "coco")
```

and produces a LaTeX list like:

```
\begin{itemize}
      \item toto
      \item tata
      \item tutu
      \item coco
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: I don't know of a library, but why not simply `cat(paste("\\item", LETTERS), sep = "\n")`?

Comment: Simply and working... Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There might be a library for this, but I am not aware of one. For the time being, the following helper function should work in most cases:

```
printList <- function(x, out.format = knitr::opts_knit$get("out.format"),
                      environment = "itemize",
                      marker = NULL) {
  if (out.format == "markdown") {
    if (!missing(environment) || !missing(marker)) {
      warning("Ignoring arguments that are not supported for markdown output.")
    }
    out <- sprintf("\n\n%s\n \n", paste("*", x, collapse = "\n"))
  } else {
    if (out.format == "latex") {
      itemCommand <- if (missing(marker)) {
        "\\item"
      } else {
          sprintf("\\item[%s]", marker)
      }
      listEnv <- c(
        sprintf("\\begin{%s}\n", environment),
        sprintf("\n\\end{%s}\n", environment))
      out <- paste(itemCommand, x, collapse = "\n")
      out <- sprintf("%s%s%s", listEnv[1], out, listEnv[2])
    } else {
      stop("Output format not supported.")
    }
  }
    return(knitr::asis_output(out))
}
@
```

It can generate markdown and LaTeX output and detects the output format automatically (`knitr::opts_knit$get("out.format")`).

For markdown, only simple lists with bullet points are supported. With LaTeX output, the default list environment is `itemize`, but any other environment can be specified using `environment`. If `marker` is set (assumed to be of the same length as `x`), it is used as optional argument for `\item`.

The function can be used both in chunks and inline.

### Demo

(copy the definition from above into the documents!):

#### RNW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
# insert definition!
@

<<results = "asis">>=
printList(LETTERS[1:3])
printList(LETTERS[1:3], environment = "enumerate")
printList(LETTERS[1:3], marker = LETTERS[24:26])
@

Inline: \Sexpr{printList(LETTERS[1:3])}
\end{document}
```

#### RMD:

````
```{r}
# insert definition!
```

```{r}
printList(LETTERS[1:3])
printList(LETTERS[1:3], environment = "enumerate") # warning
printList(LETTERS[1:3], marker = LETTERS[24:26]) # warning
```

Inline: `r printList(LETTERS[1:3])`
````